# How to split by multiple delimiters in vba excel

Tags: excel

I need to split some data  with multi delimiters (`//,/,-`) , and I used one cell (`A3`) as data entry cell and I need multi delimiters to provide multi option to the user.

and I also need to know the availability to re-arrange the splitting results like if the results involved words content (`*.com` or `*.net`) transfer to certain column

I try to use a code to split but it is working with one delimiter

Comment: and i need to know the availability to re-arrange the splitting results like if the results involved words content ((( *.com or *.net ))) transfer to certain column

Comment: Inserted comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make them the same.

Say we have a string that we want to parse by both **/** and **$**.  Here an example:

```
Sub multiparse()
    Dim s As String, s2 As String

    s = "poiuy/tyuiop$7654$lkiop/"
    s2 = Replace(s, "/", "$")
    arr = Split(s2, "$")

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but be informed that :
1- the sting is variable not fixed so i need to replace it with cell to what ever i write in the cell split

Comment: i used that code but i need to add multi delimiters : 
Dim a As Variant, cell As Range, i As Long
  For Each cell In Range(SourceRange)
    a = split(cell.Value, " // ")